pcolormesh showing white gaps between cells of data
I'm trying to graph a series of cells represented by the top left coordinate. The cells are spaced 20 units apart. When I graph the data with pcolormesh I get the individual cells with white gaps representing presumably the missing data between each cell. How can I force the cells to be 20x20 instead of 10x10?

from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap
cmap0 = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('', ['white', 'darkblue'])

eastings = range(df275.E.min(), df275.E.max()+1)
northings = range(df275.N.min(), df275.N.max()+1)

fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(8,10))
for ax, period in zip([axs], [2]):
    z = []
    for i, y in enumerate(northings):
        for j, x in enumerate(eastings):
            result = df275.query(f'E == {x} & N == {y}')
            if not result.empty:
                z.append(result[str(period)].values[0])
            else:
                z.append(0)
    ax.set(xlabel="Easting", ylabel="Northing")
    x_extents = [e + 0.5 for e in eastings]
    y_extents = [n - 0.5 for n in northings]
    ax.pcolormesh(x_extents, y_extents, np.reshape(z, (len(northings), len(eastings))), cmap=cmap0, vmin=0, vmax=max_value)
    ax.title.set_text(f"Period {period}")


I was able to solve this by creating a 2d array initially of zeros and then filling in the neighboring cells with the same data as the corner.
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap
cmap0 = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('', ['white', 'darkblue'])

fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(8,10))
for ax, period in zip([axs], [2]):
 -> z = np.zeros((len(northings), len(eastings)))
    for i, y in enumerate(northings):
        for j, x in enumerate(eastings):
            result = df275.query(f'E == {x} & N == {y}')
            if not result.empty:
            ->  value = result[str(period)].values[0]
            ->  z[i][j] = value
            ->  z[i][j+1] = value
            ->  z[i-1][j] = value
            ->  z[i-1][j+1] = value
            else:
            ->  pass
    ax.set(xlabel="Easting", ylabel="Northing")
    xlim = [e + 0.5 for e in eastings]
    ylim = [n - 0.5 for n in northings]
->  ax.pcolormesh(xlim, ylim, z, cmap=cmap0, vmin=0, vmax=max_value)
    ax.title.set_text(f"Period {period}")
    plt.grid()


